# Activity 01] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:5'

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, sdk

problem while it is installed at sdk manager
i installed project and it shows error like this plz help me out of thisActivity 01] Unable to resolve target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:5'

Answer (score 0):

You might have to clean and build the project again so that eclipse/ADT will generate a new R.java file.

Before the clean, you might want to also use the Android Context menu when you right click your project and select 'Fix Project Properties'.

Answer (score 0):

After install crashlytics I had a path Google Inc./Google APIs/17 in *project.properties*. After change it to Google Inc.:Google APIs:17 the app worked.